# facebook: wrong link gets posted to wall with php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

i have a pagetab with fangate.
on this fangate the user can click to share a link.
this is done via php sdk like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));
$message = "Win great prices!";
$wallpost = array(
'message' => $message,
'name' => 'Win Prices',
'link' => 'https://someurl.com/launcher.php',
'description' =>'I took the survey!',
'picture' => 'http://www.someurl.com/images/logo.png'
);

try
{
    $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$wallpost);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
   //
    }
```

launcher.php contains just a forwarding to the pagetab with "?ref=ts" to make it useable for mobile browsers, like:

```
<?php
header('Location: ' . "https://www.facebook.com/myGreatPage?sk=app_45532543674737&ref=ts");
?>
```

But:
The link, that gets posted, is **not** https://someurl.com/launcher.php, but the link to the pagetab https://www.facebook.com/myGreatPage?sk=app_45532543674737, which is not working for mobile devices, if they click it.
facebook seems to filter/change the link autonomously.
what can i do? do i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now i know my fault.
its not the "link"-field, that contains the link.
its the argument

```
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => 'Vote for your team','link' => 'https://blimfb.de/golfclub/app2launcher/index.php'))
```

that was missing.
so my array has to look like

```
$wallpost = array(
'message' => $message,
'name' => 'Win Prices',
'link' => 'https://someurl.com/launcher.php',
'description' =>'I took the survey!',
'picture' => 'http://www.someurl.com/images/logo.png',
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => 'I took the survey!','link' => 'https://someurl.com/launcher.php'))
);
```